# Python overwrites array in a nested function

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python and I am struggling with a nested function:

```
def compute(matrix, t, K):
    
    matrix1 = matrix
    if(t!=0):
        matrix1[t,2] = matrix1[0,0] + K
        matrix1[0,0] = 0
    
def find(matrix, K):
    x = np.array([0,1,2])
    for t in x:
        print("t = ", t)
        print("matrix = ", matrix)
        compute(matrix, t, K)

m1 = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[2,2,0]])
K1 = 11

find(m1,K1)
```

Now if I run this, `matrix` is overwritten within the nested call of `compute`:

```
t =  0
matrix =  [[1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [2 2 0]]
t =  1
matrix =  [[1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [2 2 0]]
t =  2
matrix =  [[ 0  0  0]
 [ 1  1 12]
 [ 2  2  0]]
```

Why does this happen when `matrix1` is really only created in `compute`?
How can I change that?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `matrix1 = matrix.copy()` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy))

Comment: In your 'compute()' function the line `matrix1 = matrix` does nothing for you. Even if it were to make a copy in `matrix1`, what do you think would happen next? Surely you are aware that `matrix1` would die as the function returns.

Comment: @quamrana Yes of course, I simplified my problem to this case where I don't even need it. But thanks for the reference, this really confused me but now I get it

Comment: Please update your question with some code which actually exemplifies the problem.